Wire up a shared dataset in SSRS REST API
Using the SSRS REST API , I can deploy a report from PowerShell in an automation pipeline.
But how do I use the API to wire it up to our predefined Shared DataSources?
The PUT Reports({Id})/DataSources endpoint doesn't seem to be for Shared DataSources.
Gemini suggested PATCH /Reports({id})/Properties, which understandably gave 405 Method Not Allowed, and with PUT /Reports({id})/Properties I got 400 Bad Request

I'm not sure, but you might try using a Fiddler/Postman proxy trace while using ReportBuilder to build and deploy a report based on a shared dataset.

Thank you, David Browne; the suggestion of using Fiddler to watch queries to the report server put me on the right track.
I found it makes calls to PUT .../CatalogItems({id})/Model.Report/DataSources.
I don't see that endpoint documented in the Swagger Documentation, but it seems to work.
The body is a list of data source references like this:
[
    {
        "Name":"MyDataSource",
        "Path":"/Path/to/MyDataSource",
        "IsReference":true
    }
]


I tried that but for me it did not work. I got the following error for SSRS 2022:
Invoke-WebRequest : {"error":{"code":"","message":"The entity type 'Model.CatalogItem' is not compatible with the base type 'Model.DataSource' of the provided entity set 'Model.Container.DataSources'. When an entity type is specified for an OData resource
set or resource reader, it has to be the same or a subtype of the base type of the specified entity set."}}
Instead, there is a documented REST API that can be used MS Learn
.../Reports({Id})/DataSources
When being called with a PUT request, you can use the same request body and successfully change the data source.
